# I'm trying to send temperature data from arduino to thingspeak through ESP8266, But I don't have code to configure my wifi. Please help me

Tags: arduino, iot, esp8266

I'm trying to send temperature data from arduino to thingspeak through ESP8266, But I don't have code to configure my WiFi. I'm searching for code from last two days, but not working. Please provide me code to connect to my local wifi using SSID and password.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 512
#define GET_SIZE 64
#define dbg Serial  // USB local debug
#include <dht11.h>

dht11 DHT11;

#define DHT11PIN 7
int ledPin = 13;
int lightLevel;
String apiKey = "20YMPJA0XII0IEF4";
SoftwareSerial ser(2,3);
SoftwareSerial esp(11, 12);
String ssid = "ATL-WL";
String pass = "atl#yd81";
String serverPort = "80";

char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; // Don't touch
char get_s[GET_SIZE];
char OKrn[] = "OK\r\n"; // Don't touch

String currentCommand = "0000";

byte waitForEsp(int timeout, char* term = OKrn) {
  unsigned long t = millis();
  bool found = false;
  int i = 0;
  int len = strlen(term);
  while (millis() < t + timeout) {
    if (esp.available()) {
      buffer[i++] = esp.read();
      if (i >= len) {
        if (strncmp(buffer + i - len, term, len) == 0) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  buffer[i] = 0;
  dbg.print(buffer);
  return found;
}
//Celsius to Fahrenheit conversion
double Fahrenheit(double celsius)
{
  return 1.8 * celsius + 32;
}

//Celsius to Kelvin conversion
double Kelvin(double celsius)
{
  return celsius + 273.15;
}

double dewPoint(double celsius, double humidity)
{
  // (1) Saturation Vapor Pressure = ESGG(T)
  double RATIO = 373.15 / (273.15 + celsius);
  double RHS = -7.90298 * (RATIO - 1);
  RHS += 5.02808 * log10(RATIO);
  RHS += -1.3816e-7 * (pow(10, (11.344 * (1 - 1/RATIO ))) - 1) ;
  RHS += 8.1328e-3 * (pow(10, (-3.49149 * (RATIO - 1))) - 1) ;
  RHS += log10(1013.246);

        // factor -3 is to adjust units - Vapor Pressure SVP * humidity
  double VP = pow(10, RHS - 3) * humidity;

        // (2) DEWPOINT = F(Vapor Pressure)
  double T = log(VP/0.61078);   // temp var
  return (241.88 * T) / (17.558 - T);
}

double dewPointFast(double celsius, double humidity)
{
  double a = 17.271;
  double b = 237.7;
  double temp = (a * celsius) / (b + celsius) + log(humidity*0.01);
  double Td = (b * temp) / (a - temp);
  return Td;
}
void setup() {

  pinMode(13, OUTPUT); // For debugging purposes w/o USB
  // Set baud rates
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  esp.begin(9600);
  dbg.begin(9600);
  ser.begin(9600);
  dbg.println("DEBUG: Running Setup");
  // Reset ESP, Test, Configure, Connect, Start Server
  esp.println("AT+RST"); // Reset
  waitForEsp(4000);
  esp.println("AT"); // Test
  waitForEsp(2000);
  esp.println("AT+CWMODE=1"); // Set to client mode
  waitForEsp(2000);
  esp.println("AT+CWJAP=\"" + ssid + "\",\"" + pass + "\""); // Join AP
  delay(8000); // Sometimes joining is really slow...
  waitForEsp(6000);
  esp.println("AT+CIPMUX=1"); // Allow multiple connections
  waitForEsp(2000);
  esp.println("AT+CIPSERVER=1," + serverPort); // Start server on port
  waitForEsp(2000);
  esp.println("AT+CIFSR");
  waitForEsp(1000);
  dbg.println("DEBUG: Setup complete\n\n");
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    ser.println("AT+RST");
}

void loop()
{
    // blink LED on board
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);   
  delay(200);               
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  int lightLevel = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println("\n");

  int chk = DHT11.read(DHT11PIN);

  Serial.print("Read sensor: ");
  switch (chk)
  {
    case DHTLIB_OK: 
    Serial.println("OK"); 
    break;
    case DHTLIB_ERROR_CHECKSUM: 
    Serial.println("Checksum error"); 
    break;
    case DHTLIB_ERROR_TIMEOUT: 
    Serial.println("Time out error"); 
    break;
    default: 
    Serial.println("Unknown error"); 
    break;
  }

  Serial.print("Humidity (%): ");
  Serial.println((float)DHT11.humidity, 2);

  Serial.print("Temperature (°C): ");
  Serial.println((float)DHT11.temperature, 2);

  Serial.print("Temperature (°F): ");
  Serial.println(Fahrenheit(DHT11.temperature), 2);

  Serial.print("Temperature (°K): ");
  Serial.println(Kelvin(DHT11.temperature), 2);

  Serial.print("Dew Point (°C): ");
  Serial.println(dewPoint(DHT11.temperature, DHT11.humidity));

  Serial.print("Dew PointFast (°C): ");
  Serial.println(dewPointFast(DHT11.temperature, DHT11.humidity));
  Serial.print("Light Level: ");
  Serial.println(lightLevel);
  esp_8266();
}
void esp_8266()
{
 // convert to string
  char buf[32];
  String strTemp = dtostrf( DHT11.temperature, 4, 1, buf);
  Serial.print(strTemp);
  Serial.println(" C");
  // TCP connection
  String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"";
  cmd += "184.106.153.149"; // api.thingspeak.com
  cmd += "\",80";
  ser.println(cmd);

  if(ser.find("Error")){
    Serial.println("AT+CIPSTART error");
    return;
  }

  // prepare GET string
  String getStr = "GET /update?api_key=";
  getStr += apiKey;
  getStr +="&field1=";
  getStr += String(strTemp);
  getStr += "\r\n\r\n";

  // send data length
  cmd = "AT+CIPSEND=";
  cmd += String(getStr.length());
  ser.println(cmd);

  if(ser.find(">")){
    ser.print(getStr);
  }
  else{
    ser.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
    // alert user
    Serial.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
  }

  // thingspeak needs 15 sec delay between updates
  delay(5000);  
}
//
// END OF FILE
//
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this device nor a way to test the results but a simple [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ESP8266) search [resulted](http://rancidbacon.com/files/kiwicon8/ESP8266_WiFi_Module_Quick_Start_Guide_v_1.0.4.pdf) in the following:

`AT+CWJAP="<access_point_name>","<password>"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
String ssid = "ATL-WL";
String pass = "atl#yd81";
```

to whatever your ssid and pass are for your WiFi.  I would also urge you to change:

```
String apiKey = "20YMPJA0XII0IEF4";
String ssid = "ATL-WL";
String pass = "atl#yd81";
```

completely now that you've posted them to the interwebz.

You should also ensure that you get a new API key from thingspeak.com as well.

You'll also want to ensure that CR/LF are being properly processed in your setup() loop.  You might be incorrectly assuming bad code when it could be a bad serial connection setup.